# install ros-melodic-desktop-full error

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu-xenial, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did 1.2 Setup you sources.list, then
I did 1.3 Set up your keys, then
I did Installation. All seemed like it was going well.
Then i entered the command

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full.
```

I don't get far:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full.
```

Now I'm sad. I've had ros kenetic on my system working well. But I don't know what to do.
Remove ROS again? And try adding pixie dust or water from the river jordan?
If I can not fix this I may go back to loading ROS kenetic, which was a successful install.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296135/install-ros-melodic-desktop-full-error/) by [ju78iklo9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32592/ju78iklo9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No need for pixie dust or anything else. You're trying to install Melodic onto an unsupported platform. It's targeted for 18.04. See http://wiki.ros.org/melodic#Platforms

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4